# URL Rewrite IIS 7.5 combined conditions to replace text in URL

Tags: url, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a requirement to create a rewriting rule to redirect all pages with url containing:

```
/test1/id/
```

and

```
/test2/id/
```

to:

```
/p/id
```

So far I've tried with:

```
<rule name="URL Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^test1\$" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^\test2\$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Can someone help in creating such rule?

Comment: You should include any attempts you have already made to help readers understand.

Comment: it is a redirect rule sorry for the typo.

Comment: <rule name="URL Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^test1\$" />
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="^\test2\$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>

Comment: Perhaps include this in the actual question? And use back ticks ` at the start and finish to format the code.  :)